# SCP connections mysteriously drop; too many connections?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, cygwin, sshd

I am running OpenSSH via Cygwin on a Windows 2008 server. This system acts as a file server for a pool of 30 build systems. At build time, each build system copies files as necessary from the file server, builds, and sends the results back to the file server.

When I start all of the builds in parallel, a number of them conk out due to `scp` dropping the connection (with the cryptic `Lost connection` error message). To make matters even more convoluted, each build system connects to the server using the exact same public/private key pair.

Is there a limit to how many boxes can connect to an OpenSSH server at the same time? From the [sshd_config man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config), I see that there's a **MaxSessions** parameter:

> **MaxSessions**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of open sessions permitted per network connection. The default is 10.

Is the **MaxSessions** limit what I'm running into here? If so, what's a reasonable alternative value (is 50 too high)?

Or is it perhaps some internal limitation with the keys in use? What exactly constitutes a "network connection" in terms of this setting; the socket being used or the physical port in play? Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:** When I limit my traffic to this file server (letting 5 build systems through every 5 seconds), all of them succeed. So I seem to be hitting a limit somewhere. Perhaps Windows 2008 has a connection limit of some kind?

Comment: Each client opens its own connection, so it can't be that limit. Can you watch that `wireshark`? Can you wrap the `scp` into for-loops with a sleep after each try?